# Chrome extension doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work', 11],
          ['Eat', 2],
          ['Commute', 2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep', 7]
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code generates a pie chart for us in an html file. It works when I open it in a browser. Let's call the file *popup.html*.

Then I want to make it a Chrome extension with the following manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "History Visualizer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Helps us analyze history stats in a visual way",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

But when I hit the icon button, the pie chart just won't load. Anyone help me?

**EDIT**: error message after inspecting the popup is as follows.

> Refused to load script from 'http://www.google.com/jsapi' because of
>   Content-Security-Policy.   Refused to execute inline script because of
>   Content-Security-Policy.

​

Comment: Right click on a toolbar icon of your extension, choose *Inspect Popup* from context menu, copy the error message from Console panel and paste it here. If there is no error message, try reloading the popup by executing in console: `window.location.reload();`.

Comment: @kdzwinel Thanks. Error message added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify permissions for your extension in `manifest.json` in order to use resources from `google.com`:

```
"permissions": [
  "http://*.google.com/"
],
```

Or if this won't work, try allowing your extension to access *all* URLs:

```
"permissions": [
  "<all_urls>"
],
```

Read more about permissions [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html).

Comment: Please read this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H2-3 . It looks like this library tries to use some inline javascript and this is not allowed. There is no way of relaxing this restriction to.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more. You can try to load the library without using `google.load` if possible (I think that the loader may be trying to `eval` something). Or better yet, download it and include in your extension.

Comment: Mmm, I think the problem is that the script isn't allowed to load in the first place, due to CSP. You need to modify the CSP in order to include any external scripts, and they have to be over HTTPS. And the inline scripts that Chrome is complaining about are part of `popup.html` in the first place, not the fault of the chart API. (Sorry for bumping! Just in case it helps anyone else.)