# Google Chart in Chrome Extension Popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-visualization

I would like to have my Chrome extension's popup page display a Google Chart that shows information on the user's news-reading habits. I notice (particularly here: [Chrome extension doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799257/chrome-extension-doesnt-work)) that a problem with this is that Chrome extensions do not allow inline script, which complicates including the necessary API files to use Google Chart. Is there a way around this? Is there somewhere where I can download the entirety of the API to simply include in my extension?

Comment: Isn't this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799257/chrome-extension-doesnt-work#comment14051301_10799671) good enough?

Comment: I was hoping for some more detail, or possibly an alternative. You'll notice I linked to that thread in the original post, and that it doesn't provide much of an answer - if there is no more of an answer, I'd like to know.

Comment: **There is no way of relaxing this restriction too.** Seems like a definitive answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Google Charts if the document is in the Chrome extension's context because it violates the inline-JavaScript rule. However, you can put an iframe into the extension's popup that references a remote resource. For instance, if the below snippet is in your popup:

```
<iframe src="https://mycoolextension.com/user/12345"></iframe>
```

Then you can have an application using Google Charts available at the address https://mycoolextension.com/user/12345. If you want to integrate the charts with the extension's data, you will either need to add parameters to the chart iframe's address, or implement a content script to message values into the iframe.

Answer (score 5):

An extension can, in principle, use a library that violates CSP. However, that requires an additional hoop to jump: [Sandboxing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox).

```
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "sandbox.html"
    ]
    "content_security_policy":
        "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google.com/jsapi"
  ],
```

It was specifically created to address this issue. See the ["Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely."](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval) guide for implementation details.

You will need to communicate the results between your normal scripts and sandbox, as sandboxed pages have no Chrome API access.