# How to use Google Charts library into Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api

How can I use Google Charts in one of my Options page in Chrome Extension?

According to Google [TOS](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#localdownload) I cannot download Google Charts. And when I try to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>` it obviously return error saying:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={%27modules%27:[{%27name%27:%27visualization%27,%27version%27:%271%27,%27packages%27:[%27corechart%27]}]}' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com 'unsafe-eval'".
```

I even tried to put following line of code in manifest file, to make an exception:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google.com/jsapi; object-src 'self'",
```

But no luck.

Does anyone have any idea on how this can be done? I cannot have this chart show up in an iframe because the data will be different for each user and Our API uses OAuth2 authentication method. So serving charts from different page is not a best solution.

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348868/google-chart-in-chrome-extension-popup

Comment: Thanks @gui47 But I cannot use iframe approach. I have edited my question above.

Comment: Your only other option is [sandboxing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox). I am going to vote to close this as a duplicate, but consider that there _is_ an alternative. I don't have a ready solution to put as an answer.

Comment: thats ok. I went with another chart library. Thanks.